# Capturar primera letra de una palabra ingresada en C

Tags: c

Hola estoy intentando capturar la primera letra de una palabra de tipo `char` para guardar  la letra en un indice de un arreglo definido, no puedo utilizar cadenas de `string`.

```
while (cont<=i-1){

    scanf("%c",&respuesta);
    getchar();
    b[cont]=respuesta;      
}
cont++;
```

también probé con:

```
while (cont<=i-1){

    scanf("%c",& b[cont]);
    getchar();
}
cont++;
```

Cunando ingreso Azul captura `z` necesito capturar la `A`.

Comment: Tienes la *A* en *respuesta* (primer ejemplo) o *b[0]* (segundo ejemplo).

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones el código completo? así podremos ver dónde está el problema exactamente

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código creo que se asemeja a lo que tu quieres. Es un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {

char c[100];
scanf("%s",c);   
printf("%c",c[0]);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo podria ser tan simple como esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char c;
 char arreglo[100];

 printf("Ingresar\n");
 scanf("%c", &c);
 arreglo[1]=c;
 printf("letras: %c", c);
 return 0;
}
```

Esto seria ejemplo para guardarlo en una posicion especifica. Luego tu incorporas a tu ciclo repetitivo